# Spring 5 Reactive - Why that code doesn't consume CPU?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I'm testing springboot 2.0.0.M3 with spring-webflux and mongodb-reactive driver
and don't understand why my code doesn't consume CPU (less than 2%).
Memory is ok (70% used in 32GB), I/O are low (hard drive is silently :) )
And Finally i have an error

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: Query failed with
>   error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 26041128255 not found on
>   server localhost:27017' on server localhost:27017

I suspect that it tooks too long and after 10 minutes, it throws this exception.

Here the code :

```
usedKeyRepository.findAll()
   .buffer(4096).parallel()
   .concatMap(listUsedKey -> generatedKeyRepository.bulkFindGeneratedKeysByPub(listUsedKey.stream().map(u -> u.getPub()).collect(Collectors.toSet())))
   .subscribe(clefsTrouvees -> recordMatches(clefsTrouvees),
              ex -> LOG.error("my exception", ex)
);
```

```java
private void recordMatches(GeneratedKey clefGeneree) {
   LOG.warn("clef : priv:{}\tpub:{}", clefGeneree.getPriv(), clefGeneree.getPub());
}
```

the usedKeyRepository.findAll() method is

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveMongoTemplate template;

public Flux<UsedKey> findAll() {
   return template.findAll(UsedKey.class);
}
```

```java
public Flux<GeneratedKey> bulkFindGeneratedKeysByPub(final Collection<String> pub) {
   Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("pub").in(pub));
   return template.find(query, GeneratedKey.class);
}
```

My collection usedKey contains 8 millions doc and generatedkey contains 650 millions.
Any ideas ? :-/

Comment: Looks like a query timeout to me; you could maybe batch those queries by page to avoid streaming everything in one query?

Comment: Hum, i've tried it, the findAll seems to be ok, perhaps the bulkFindGeneratedKeysByPub, but it should produce a high CPU load, but it is less than 2% :-/
My search in collections are well indexed
In addition, in my code, i've put the line .buffer(4096) to produce batchs to avoid streaming :)

Comment: You need to narrow things down then - just logging all results from findAll works? Are your log statements printing something?

Comment: the lambda clefsTrouvees -> recordMatches(clefsTrouvees) is rarely called, perhaps never call. The code search for a match in two collections :)
I have get some call to this method, and it was ok, but just 3 or 4 calls

Comment: Looks like a lot of time is eaten up by MongoDB itself and eventually, the original cursor expires. I suggest you reduce the buffer size to a smaller number (128) and that you [trace your queries in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) to see what's going on.